# Segueing custom view cells to custom view controller

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using a collection view to display a grid of custom collection view cells to represent category icons that will function as buttons to segue to a table view controller to display the categories listings. I'm using an array of "products" (labels) and "images" (images of the products) to display multiple custom cells based off a prototype as such

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.images[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelView?.text = self.products[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

How would be able to segue my home page view controller to a single custom table view controller to display different category listings depending on which icon was selected? Any help is greatly appreciated, still getting used to xcode and swift

Comment: I need some clarification.

Are you asking how to segue from one VC to another? Or asking how to segue to different VCs depending on which cell is selected? Or how to triage the selection of the cell?

Comment: Segueing to different VCs depending on which cell is selected is the closest to what I was getting at.  I want each cell when selected to display the categories listings (this is a basic shopping application for HW) in the same manner in a tableview. I was hoping to be able to create a prototype table view cell with an imageView on the left and a description as a label in the center of each "listing" the selected category cell has.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the same child UITableViewController and pass it different data depending on what cell is chosen.

First in the CollectionViewController implement

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Then perform the segue with the data

```
performSegue("identifier", sender: self.products[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: My next question would be how to assign an object which contains an array of UIImage (pictures of listings) and an array of strings (description of listings) to which specific icon that is being selected. Would this object be the sender in the performSegue method?

Comment: Maybe I could use a series of case statements to determine which data be displayed in the tableview controller after clicking on the icon at a specific index in the main view controller?

Comment: Ideally you would store the data in an array, indexed to the same indexes you're using for the text/image arrays, than only pass the necessary data to your next ViewController

Answer (score 0):

First your view controller has to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` then you have to implement this delegate method to perform a segue when a cell is selected:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Then check if the segue identifier matches, get `indexPath` of the selected cell, construct a tuple of the selected product and image and finally pass it to your destination `tableViewController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!.first!
        let selectedProduct = (product: products[indexPath.row], image: images[indexPath.row])
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! YourTableViewController
        controller.product = selectedProduct
    }
}
```